# Is there a faster way in R of creating large dataframe without loops?

Tags: r, performance, loops

Below is an example of what I'm currently doing and it's rather slow.   I figure that there must be something more efficient than this since it takes about 95 seconds to run.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 1000, 1000))     
for (i in (1:1000)) {
        for (j in (i:1000)) {
                df[i, j]  <-   i *1000 + j  
                df[j, i]  <-   df[i, j]  

        }
}
```

Also note that the i*1000+j is just for illustration.  I'm doing something else there, but it's a calculation dependent on getting all the pairs for 1:1000.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `outer` with a re-assignment of lower triangle of matrix return.

```
out_mat <- outer(1:1E3, 1:1E3, function(i,j) i * 1E3 + j)
out_mat[lower.tri(out_mat)] <- t(out_mat)[lower.tri(t(out_mat))]
df2 <- data.frame(out_mat)
```

Results show exact equivalent of *df* generated from `for` loop:

```
identical(df, df2)
# [1] TRUE
```

However, above depends on your *actual* calculation as beyond simple arithmetic, the `outer` call may not work depending on the dimensions.

Comment: That's much faster.   Thanks.  My actual calculation is ``` set.seed(42)
dfA <- data.frame(replicate(10 ,sample(LETTERS,1000,rep=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = F)
dfB <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS, Price = as.numeric(sample(1:100, 26, replace=FALSE)), stringsAsFactors = F)

myFunction <- function (A, B) {
        if (A == B) {
                return(1)
        } else {
                x <- intersect(t(dfA[A, ]), t(dfA[B, ]))     
                return(sum(dfB$Price[match(x, dfB$ID)])/1000)  
        }
}    ```  which is also very slow.